# Why can't I change my disabled checkbox to enable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, disable

Simple question, so I made sure to try and a lot of solutions before posting this. I have a checkbox and I can't seem to enable it.

With vanilla JS, I've tried removing the attribute, as well as setting the disabled flag to false, and also using jQuery i've tried to use the Prop to no success.

'''html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkAllowToAdminService" name="chkAllowToAdminService" disabled="disabled" data-init-plugin="switchery">
```

'''

I've tried the following and none of them are working (vanilla JS and jQuery)

'''

```
document.getElementById('chkAllowToAdminService').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('chkAllowToAdminService').removeAttribute('disabled);
$('#chkAllowToAdminService').prop("disabled", false);
```

'''

No error messages at all, just nothing seems to be happening.

Comment: [your code works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/hv74b9x3/) - both vanilla code attempts do https://jsfiddle.net/hv74b9x3/1/ ... once you fix the missing `'` - and the [jQuery version works just as well](https://jsfiddle.net/hv74b9x3/2/) - so ... you're doing something else wrong if you're not getting ANY errors in the console

Comment: `removeAttribute('disabled);` is missing a closing single-quote after `disabled` maybe create a snippet so we can replicate the bug here.

Answer (score 0):

// In jQuery

```
$('#chkAllowToAdminService').attr('disabled','disabled'); // Add disabled
$('#chkAllowToAdminService').removeAttr('disabled',''); // Remove disabled
```

// OR

```
$("#chkAllowToAdminService").attr("disabled",true);
$("#chkAllowToAdminService").attr("disabled",false);
```

// In JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("chkAllowToAdminService").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("chkAllowToAdminService").disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove attribute you may use [removeAttribute(name)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute). In your case:

```js
const checkbox = document.querySelector('#chkAllowToAdminService')

checkbox.removeAttribute('disabled')
```

To set attribute [setAttribute(name, value)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

Answer (score 0):

**I think you might have two issue :**

1. make sure you have unique id of element `'chkAllowToAdminService'` no other element have same id.
2. in your remove attribute syntex : `document.getElementById('chkAllowToAdminService').removeAttribute('disabled);`
   I can see quote `'` is missing at last.

Comment: fixed the typo and confirmed only one element has that unique ID, still not working. If I remove the disabled="disabled" property from the html element, I can't even set it to disabled in javascript

Comment: @edward can you please share code via jsbin.com so we can understand issue batter .